Ubuntu installer 24.04 black screen display on standby
When using the Ubuntu 24.04 installer (USB drive was formatted as MBR) on legacy BIOS machine with NVIDIA GTX 750 graphics card upon booting from USB media I get to a black screen and eventually the screen goes on standby. The only way to boot from a USB is with Safe graphics mode. Does that mean that my graphics card is an issue, and I won't be able to install Ubuntu 24.04? Does Ubuntu 24.04 version support legacy BIOS systems?

Ubuntu 24.04 supports legacy BIOS systems. There is even a legacy BIOS only bootable Ubuntu 24.04 Minimal USB for installing Ubuntu 24.04.
Safe graphics mode during installation likely doesn't utilize the  discrete graphics card to its full potential, but booting your computer in Safe graphics mode will not prevent you from installing Ubuntu on it. Safe graphics mode in Ubuntu uses the VESA driver which prioritizes hardware compatibility over utilizing the advanced features of a graphics card. This permits the Ubuntu installer to be compatible with a wider range of devices.

The Nvidia graphics driver isn't compatible with Wayland. You have to select Xorg at the login screen instead.

Note that during or after the Ubuntu install, a more appropriate driver can be installed that will use more of the capabilities of the gpu.  It may or may not work with wayland however.
